# Writing to an internal Json File on Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am writing an Android app that uses a JSON File that is internal to the app, aka on the root of the project or in the assets file(both are ok).

But when attempting to write to it I get:

```
open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

How can I deal with this?

Comment: post your code.

Comment: provide some code

Comment: you can't write to your APK file (assets are stored inside APK). It is read-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write to files in your APK, since they are read-only. That's why you're getting the EROFS. What you could do, is read the file and copy its contents. You should be able to edit the copied version. Dont forget to save the edited copy (can be done in SharedPreferences for example).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by first copying the file to getFilesDir at runtime.

Thanks for the help